# Necessary conditions on $x$ for $e^{ax} \geq b - cx$.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, exponential-function

Let $a,c>0$, $b>1$  be constants. I am wondering what kind of necessary conditions we can find in order that

$$ e^{ax} \geq b - cx$$

holds. So I would like something like

$$ e^{ax} \geq b - cx \Rightarrow x \geq f(a,b,c)$$

where $f$ is some fairly simple function (not something esoteric like the Lambert W-function).

Graphically speaking, it is clear that  the equation

$$ e^{ax} = b - cx$$

has precisely one solution, which is positive.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: What are possible values of $x$?

Comment: Given it is a simple expression using the Lambert W $x \ge b/c - 1/a W\left(a e^{a b/c}/c\right)$, very doubtful you will get a simple function without using it.

Comment: I am only looking for a necessary condition, not a necessary and sufficient condition. So if the Lambert function could be crudely approximated somehow, this would be good enough for me.